# SQLPlus results in one line

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have an user table where I am looking for user ids with name john

```
select USER_ID from user where USER_ID like '%john%';
```

I get

```
USER_ID
-------
john1
john2
john3
```

Is there a way I can display that information back from SQLPlus as a single line? like

```
john1, john2, john3
```

Comment: sql*plus doesn't have this kind of functionality, you have to pivot your data yourself, using listagg or pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using 11.2 (the `oracle11g` tag could also mean 11.1)

```
select listagg( user_id, ',' ) within group (order by user_id )
  from user
 where user_id like '%john%';
```

For a canonical list of the various string aggregation techniques that are available in different versions of Oracle, I'd recommend Tim Hall's article on [string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the pivot queries in Oracle 11g. http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506